# React native geolication don't work on device

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I try to use **React-native-geolocation** *(from react-native-community/react-native-geolocation)* in my app, with `React Native 0.60.5`.
But, that not work. I try a lot of things, do research on the web, but no result. On the emulator, no problem. But on any device, I've got no result.

Is someone use this package ? Or another for replacement ? 
Thanks a lot
(And sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used it this way:

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  ({coords: {latitude, longitude}}) => {
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0143,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0134,
      },
    });
  },
  error => {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  },
  {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
  },
);
```

And I added this setting in file AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I use but this not work for me :/ do you import another thing then react-native-community/geolication ?

Comment: No, the versions I am using:  
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-maps": "0.25.0"